# GMail API not working properly when minifyEnabled=true

Tags: android, gmail-api, android-proguard

I am developing an Android app that sends e-mails using the GMail API. I have used the example code at [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) and [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) and everything works fine when I debug the app. 
The problem arises when I build the release version with `minifyEnabled=true`. In that case, the call to `service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();` goes into error with `IOException`. The message of the exception is "404 Not Found".

The Proguard file includes all the `-keep class` and `-dontwarn` that I have found in other posts:

```
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**

-keep class com.google.**
-keep public class Mail {*;}
-keep class com.sun.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.activation.registries {*;}
-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}
```

I don't think it is a problem of credentials as e-mails are sent if I sign the app with `minifyEnabled=false`. I also tested the release version of the app on the emulator, setting `minifyEnabled=true` and `debuggable=true`. In this case e-mails are sent but the APK is larger when it is debuggable so I think that something fundamental is retained ase.

Dependecies in the gradle file are the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev47-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.5'
}
```

I am not sure about `exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'` but removing it does not solve the problem.

Comment: `-keep class com.google.** {*;}` instead of `-keep class com.google.**` solved the problem, though not sure this is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this exact same issue and while your `-keep class com.google.** {*;}` does fix the problem, it's a bit heavy handed and may leave things unprotected that you don't want unprotected. As per the [Google API Documentation regarding ProGaurd](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup#proguard), you should add the following lines to your ProGuard configuration.

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
```

This allows the Google APIs to work properly while being protected with ProGuard.